# I want regular expression for first occurrence in the first line

Tags: regex

Here is the text.

```
H:46"  W:22.75"  D:24.5"
Inside: W:15.5"  D:17"
COM Requirements: 3 yds
COL Requirements: 54 sq ft
Also Available: 73-26 26" Seat Height
```

I need to find out width for the first occurrence in the first line. I want width `22.75`.

I also try out with [regex.com](https://regexr.com/)

[image]

Here i find out two occurrences for width

now I use `W:(\d+\.?\d*)\1` for the first occurrence but i can't find it out.

Comment: You may use: `W:(\d+\.?\d*)`

Comment: I already use this. but I want first occurrence

Comment: @anubhava okay got it. i need to remove `\g`.

Comment: Also your use of `\1` is not correct. `\1` represents back-reference of group #1 which is actual decimal number. So your regex will only match same decimal appearing twice adjacent to each other after matching `W:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the global (`g`) flag and it will only return the first match. i.e. `/W:(\d+\.?\d*)/` instead of `/W:(\d+\.?\d*)/g`

Answer (score 0):

use from `lookbehind` and `lookahead`:

```
/(?<=W:)(\d+\.?\d*)(?=")/g
```

To be more precise and to avoid errors, it is best to specify the pattern before and after.
test: [Link](http://regexr.com/4me67)

Comment: Please add some description to your code explaining what is going on and why. This is good practice. If you don't, your answer is in risk of being deleted. It has already been flagged as low quality.